# How to select/run any kernel among those installed

Tags: kernel

I updated my kernel. However, problems have arisen after that. So I started to download multiple kernels and install them through

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

I thought that at any time, the kernel was changing. However, among all version, my computer still see the latest version. All my installed kernels are now:

```
ii  linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic                    5.3.0-18.19+1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.3.0-40-generic                    5.3.0-40.32                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                             5.3.0.40.34                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.6.0-050600rc3-lowlatency 5.6.0-050600rc3.202002240232           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.6.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.6.0-050600rc4-lowlatency 5.6.0-050600rc4.202003012332           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.6.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.6.0-050600rc5-lowlatency 5.6.0-050600rc5.202003082130           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.6.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

The one used by my acutal Ubuntu is the last one.
How can I select a different version to run?

Comment: Select the kernel at boot using GRUB. See [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Comment: Hi @user535733, the Grub is that selection mode at boot where you can choose between Ubuntu and Windows? As in that case, I did not have the kernel option. Or is it in the "advanced Ubuntu" option?

Comment: Did you remember to run `update-grub` after installing those kernel packages? Also, those look like unsigned kernels - did you remember to disable Secure Boot?

Comment: @user535733 Yeah! I'll do that now!

Comment: Then, yes, it'll be in under the "advanced" options. grub should have been updated as part of installing those kernels.